# How to do a report in odoo 11

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-11

I'm a beginner on Odoo and I want to customize the report that already exists in sale and so I made an inherit of sale But my code shows me an error that is:
Error while validating the constraint .... cannot be located in the parent view

In addition to that if I execute just the first part it works but it directly modifies the report of dirty but the report in my module is remain empty.

Here is the code:

```
<template id="report_real_estate_rental_in" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//span[@t-field='doc.name']" position="after">
        <p>JE SUIS LA</p>
    </xpath>
</template>

<template id="report_real_estate_rental">
    <t  t-call = "web.html_container" >
        <t  t-foreach = "docs"  t-as = "o" >
            <t  t-call = "web.external_layout" >
                <div  class = "page" >
                    <t t-call="report_real_estate_rental_in"/>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when xpath expression cannot be located in parent view. Please make sure the xpath expression is correct and template id you're inheriting is correct. Check out this [link](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/) for inheriting and modifying existing report in Odoo.

Comment: In my template, when I modify the structure, my report does not change, I can not understand why it remains the same

Comment: @CherifiFares make sure you,re inheriting correct module and call xml file in manifest

Comment: I did it and i inherit the correct module. My report remains frozen but the report that I inherit (dirty) takes the changes I make.

Comment: @CherifiFares did you bind this report to your module

Answer (score -1):

If i got the question as you meant , when you use `t-call` you have to include the module name also , so it will be `module_name.template_id`.

In your case , change it as `<t t-call="your_module_name.report_real_estate_rental_in"/>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. but the problem is always the same